# Hot to set all response's header in SpringMVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, cors

I'm looking to solve the CORS problem. So I tried to use:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

It worked. But I have to write it everywhere. Is there a way to simplify it?

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/manage/getEncloser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public String getEncloser(@RequestParam Map<String, String> filter, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // TODO CORS    
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    return JSONObject.toJSONString(encloserService.list(filter));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional way, you can write a Servlet filter to do that. Here is an example using filter for CORS problem. See below link for reference:
https://gist.github.com/zeroows/80bbe076d15cb8a4f0ad

BTW, Spring Framework offers several ways to deal with CORS. You can take a look at below link:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: can't open the second link